# How to save the data from the post request in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, http-post

I was trying to implement a comment in a blog using a POST method. I want to save get the data by POST method of name, email, text and save it to the database. Also, the date field should get the date.now() and blog field should get the Blog or id of the Blog. The code looks like this -

models.py :

```
from django.db import models

class Blog......


class Comment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=0)
    blog = models.ForiegnKey(Blog_tables, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    Text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Text
```

views.py

```
from .models import Blog, Comment
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect



def blog_detail(request, blog_id):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'home/detail.html', {'blog': blog})

def post_comment(request, blog_id):
    # Here's a post code to be implemented. Please read the commented text

    # 'blog' field of models will get the id of the blog
    # 'name' field will get the POST method value of input name="name"
    # 'email' field will get the POST method value of input name="email"
    # 'text' field will get the POST method value of input name="text"
    # 'date' will get the current Date 
    # All the above data will be saved in the database
```

html template : blog_detail.html

```
<html>
  <body>
<!--...Blog Text Here...-->

<!-- Comment Section -->

        <form action="/blogs/{{blog_id}}/comment" method ="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"/>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email"/>
            <input type="text" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Comments here"/>


            <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me out to solve the Prolem.

The layout of the form is as follows:
[image]

Please help me to get the value from the comment section in the layout and save it to the database

I have also tried this in 
views.py :

```
def post_comment(request, blog_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get("name", "email", "comment")
       # blog = get_object_or_404(Blog_tables, pk=blog_id)
        p = Blog_Comment_table(blog= data.name, comment_name=data.email, 
comment_email= data.email, comment_Text= data.comment, comment_data = 
timezone.now())
        p.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        return render(request, '/blogs/' + blog_id + '/comment', {'error_message': 'Error'})
```

Comment: *What* is the problem? What have you tried? Have you read the tutorial or any of the other extensive documentation on POSTs and forms?

Comment: I have already read the documentation. But it didn't helped me

Comment: Why not? *What did you try*?

Comment: There are 4 field in comment table. blog, name, email, comment where blog is blog id of the blog for ex. 0 or 1 or 2, etc. and the name, email, comment will get the data through the post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
from django.utils import import timezone
from .forms import CommentForm

def post_comment(request, blog_id):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = CommentForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           data = form.cleaned_data
           blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=blog_id)
           Comment.objects.create(
               blog = blog,
               name = data.name
               email = data.email
               text = data.text
               date = timezone.now()
           )
```

Comment: I was getting the error "get() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given" when tried the code